# Grep command -ov flag

Tags: linux, grep

I was playing around with grep command and I noticed that `grep -ov unix Geekfile.txt` does not work.
On the other hand, `grep -ov unix Geekfile.txt` prints a result

my Geekfile.txt is

```
Unix is great os. 
unix is opensource. 
unix is free os.
learn operating system.
Unix linux which one you choose.
uNix is easy to learn.
unix is a multiuser os.
Learn unix .
unix is a powerful
```

Shouldn't it print rest of the lines like this:-

```
learn operating system.
Unix linux which one you choose.
uNix is easy to learn.
```

Comment: Both commands are the same. Edit you question to fix it

Comment: Also explain what is "don't work"

Answer (score 1):

This option will not work together

- -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN`
- -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines

You can not say you should get only match using `-v` and then invert it `-o`. It will not combine.

```
grep -o unix file
unix
unix
unix
unix
unix
```

and

```
grep -v unix file
Unix is great os.
learn operating system.
Unix linux which one you choose.
uNix is easy to learn.
```